# How to get indefinite integral of the following?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

The question is as following :

$$\int \frac {e^{3x}}3 dx$$

I dont understand what to do when there is a number to the power of $x$. I would greatly appreciate anyones help.

Comment: Hint (for the problem):  What is the derivative of $e^{3x}$?  What is the derivative of $\lambda e^{3x}$ for constant $\lambda$?

Comment: Have added the MathJax - to do a fraction, we use `$\frac{x}{y}$` to get $\frac{x}{y}$

Comment: Hint (for typesetting):  I reformatted your question...if you click on the edit button you should be able to see the syntax that was used.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly you can write $$\int  \frac { e^{ 3x } }{ 3 } dx=\frac { 1 }{ 9 } \int  e^{ 3x }d\left( 3x \right) =\frac { e^{ 3x } }{ 9 } +C$$

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is via [substitution](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/SubstitutionRuleIndefinite.aspx):
$$\int \frac{e^{3x}}{3}~dx$$
And let
$$u=e^{3x} \implies du=3e^{3x}~dx \implies du=3u~dx\implies dx=\frac{1}{3u}~du$$

Comment: Why let $u=e^{3x}$? Should it be u=3x?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but where does 'u' fit into this question? Thank you.

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Yes, that is another way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it seems you're doing it too long.--) Anyway, at least you did it in a different approach.

Comment: @AlanPiggott See [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/SubstitutionRuleIndefinite.aspx).